# How can my app parse twitter (xml or json) response [200 or 401]?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, curl, twitter

How can my app parse the Twitter response when someone using a curl command, like this:

curl -v -H 'X-Auth-Service-Provider: https://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json' -H 'X-Verify-Credentials-Authorization: OAuth realm="http://api.twitter.com/", oauth_consumer_key="******jhtmLUypg82g", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_token="419590-jkI7yGUDRmykzVKrgoLhXSq67TEa5ruc4GJCwbgakU", oauth_timestamp="1278339950", oauth_nonce="bgHjmTTQIZvqvlfXM5dsYxnoGD0AQR3Fmi7Q6Y", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature="RbNmGfE7Rs9J1kafTGwuUikLh4o%3D"'  -F "file=@/path/to/file" http//myapp.com/upload.json

how can i check if twitter response returns 200 code or 401 (Unauthorized) in order procced the file handling..?

any help will be highly appreciated :-)

Comment: Who is this "someone", and what role are they playing in all this? Are you simply wanting to parse the text output from `curl` to find the HTTP status code?

Comment: "Someone" is a some user who wants to upload a file. Yes, I want simply to parse the output!